# Doxygen puts table on new page when using latex output

Tags: doxygen

I have a table in a piece of markdown documentation being fed into doxygen. For latex output, the table is placed on the next page. However for HTML output the table is properly flowed out on the screen.

How do I make it put the table on the same page as the other text? Is this just some behavior of the `tabular` environment in latex?

Here's an example of what the markdown looks like

```
# Heading 1
Some text.

# Heading 2
This section does blah blah.
<!-- Here the page is broken, even though it shouldn't be -->
Col 1 | Col2 | Col3
----- | ---- | -----
12    | 4556 | 90438
jfdk  | kjds | cat
bat   | some | day

Some more text <!-- this remains on the same page as the table -->
```

Doxygen Version: 1.8.9.1
pdflatex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)

## I figured it out.

Apparently, if the contents of the page gets, really close to the bottom, and then there is a heading it causes this behavior for some reason. However, so long as there is some content before the next heading. This will not occur.

Comment: I created a aa.md with the given code and created a default Doxyfile (doxygen -g). Ran doxygen and generated the pdf output, all looks fine everything on one page. Used versions on Windows: doxygen 1.8.9.1 and MikTex 2.9. Which versions are you using?

Comment: @albert I added the doxygen version. Also, I tried the text above, and it does work. So maybe it has to do with page length.